# Complete action to open a file using different application "always"

Tags: default-applications

I'm running a Galaxy Note 3 with stock Android Lollipop. I'm aware how it has worked for years with Android when one can choose an application for a certain type of action or file type, and also choosing to just use it this once it always. And if choosing as always this can then be reverted by clearing the defaults of that app. However the case as in the following image is new to me.

In this case I'd like to use the native "create contact" always. How would I do that?

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

As you can see I can't choose it together with always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to choose the native contact app once, and the next time Android ask you, you will be able to set it as default

Comment: That was my first thought, so I tried it right away but I only keep getting the screen I posted no matter which app I choose.

Comment: Can you tell me what app you are using?

Comment: I retried this today and this time it worked the way you stated. I'm positive I tried that multiple times before asking this question. Must have been a bug. Anyway, thank you.